# Retrieve dictionary elements based on order

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Example creation of Dictionary: Dictionary processes Elements in arbitrary fashion. Hence I get the output in mixed order which doesnt correlate with my list x.

```
x = [100,2,300,4,75]
    dct = {}
    for i in x:
        dct['lst_%s' % i] = []
        for z in range(0,5):
            dct['lst_%s' % i].extend((x[z],x[z-1]))
    print(dct)
    {'lst_300': [100, 75, 2, 100, 300, 2, 4, 300, 75, 4], 'lst_75': [100, 75, 2, 100, 300, 2, 4, 300, 75, 4], 'lst_100': [100, 75, 2, 100, 300, 2, 4, 300, 75, 4], 'lst_2': [100, 75, 2, 100, 300, 2, 4, 300, 75, 4], 'lst_4': [100, 75, 2, 100, 300, 2, 4, 300, 75, 4]}
```

Using sorted key I do get dictionary headers in order corresponding to my list x but how can I retrieve the elements for the same ?

```
x = [100,2,300,4,75]
dct = {}
for i in x:
    dct['lst_%s' % i] = []
    for z in range(0,5):
        dct['lst_%s' % i].extend((x[z],x[z-1]))
print(sorted(dct))
['lst_100', 'lst_2', 'lst_300', 'lst_4', 'lst_75']
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unsorted by definition. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? :)

Comment: I would like to have the dct arranged according to the x elements: for example list_100, list_2, list_300 and list_75 with their corresponding element list.

Comment: See the answer below. Dicts are unordered. Period. You can't order them, you can only order keys in a list and then loop through dict in that order, but you can't order a dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict` is unordered by definition. If you really want an ordered map, use `collections.OrderedDict`